# How to migrate to code review

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

Related: [On migrating from SO: how to do this efficiently and appropriately.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/on-migrating-from-so-how-to-do-this-efficiently-and-appropriately)

I've just come accross a question which I believe is ideal for code review. However it's already got an accepted answer.

I can't flag that it should go on code review, and I'm not sure flagging is the best approach.

Should I ignore or flag the question?

In general (assuming no accepted answers) how should I mark questions as suitable for CR?

The question in question is [How can I reduce the Cyclomatic Complexity of this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853343/how-can-i-reduce-the-cyclomatic-complexity-of-this)

**EDIT 1**

To *me* this is the definition of a proper code review question.

- Its a beginner who is asking about best practice.
- It contains functional code.
- There are several comments already which are off topic for SO about the use of instanceof and proper OO practices.

Code review could give better answers because more of the other information that is being freely offered is on topic there.

Infact the most upvoted answer pretty much is talking about practices. Not the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think it should be migrated if it already has an accepted answer - it still is on topic on SO. But I'm not familiar with the rules regarding this, so I can be wrong.

Comment: yeah I kinda thought that

Comment: @Pekka: Just because it has an accepted answer doesn't mean that it is on-topic or welcome. I also think that this would fit better on CR, but it's also on-topic on SO, since he's asking a specific programming question.

Comment: Yes it is on topic. :S

Comment: @Bobby - there are two reasons to migrate. One - it's off topic for the current site. Two - even though it's on topic it would get better answers on another site. Neither of these reasons apply in this case. The question is on topic for SO and it already has an acceptable answer.

Comment: Is everyone in agreement it should stay where it is? I think it may get better answers on another site because those answers would be on topic. This question already has several comments relating to using instanceof and relating to OOP patterns. These comments are much more on topic on code review.

Comment: I don't think Code Review would add significantly different answers at this point. I agree with ChrisF.

Comment: @AnnaLear @ChrisF @Wes @Bobby @Pekka are we asking about this _type_ of question or about _this_ question?

Comment: @drachenstern I was asking in general but with a specific example

Answer (score 5):

@Malachi almost said it all. I'll only add this:

From the [CodeReview Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> [For a question] to be on-topic the answer **must be yes to *all* questions:**
>
> - Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> - Did I write that code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

Code-review SO questions that pass the above test *should* be migrated. Ignoring them, not migrating them or closing them as off-topic is likely to just frustrate the OP and, when/if they find out about CR, encourages cross-posting.

Migrating good CR candidates, however, can have a highly positive impact on CR traffic (and voting!), as migrated questions still show up in SO's questions list. [One of the latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789660/how-can-i-improve-my-code?noredirect=1) SO questions migrated to CR actually made it to the top of that week's *top hits* in the CR weekly newsletter. Wasn't a really great question, not even an exciting code review (was a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) question with trivial code), but it was nice to see votes pile up on a CR question (~125 votes generated with the top 3 answers), and I think a big part of that was all thanks to the visibility granted by migration.

Answer (score 3):

when I want to flag a question for Code Review I just use the

```
other (needs ♦ moderator attention)
```

option on the flag option list and then say why I think it should be moved to Code Review.  sometimes the Moderator says no.

from what I understand, the reason why it isn't an option to migrate to Code Review is because it is still a Beta Site, so flagging it that way is the only way to get it migrated. (As far as I know)

Comment: +1 Yep, pretty much.  I also like this method because it allows the mods to decide if the question belongs on CR, rather than letting other (possibly unsure) users decide.  There have been situations where something migrated to CR was still off-topic.  That just frustrates the OP and the rest of us.

Comment: best way I think.  but gives the moderators a lot of stuff to do if there are a lot of questions being flagged

Comment: True, but I still think it's better to let the moderators decide, especially if there's uncertainty.  Although not entirely related, Winston Ewert says [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/797/22222) that we should flag if a question seems good for migration.  Granted, this is because we cannot migrate questions anywhere but Meta Code Review, but moderators would still have a better idea about what to do.