# How does one get a question moved to Code Review

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate to code review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89799/how-to-migrate-to-code-review)

This question is an excellent candidate for the site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

[Can you think of a better way to increment this integer when looping through a collection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661647/can-you-think-of-a-better-way-to-increment-this-integer-when-looping-through-a-c)

But I am not a moderator, nor is there a voting button to move it...so how does a lowly 600 level person like me get that process started (not just for the above question, but going foward)?

Note I viewed this question [How to migrate to code review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89799/how-to-migrate-to-code-review) but there was no answer.

Is this a feature request for a migrate option? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There is a `flag` link below each question. Flag it for moderator love, use the [x] other comment field to issue such requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flag it for moderator attention, choose the "other" option, then type in your justifcation for why it should be migrated to Code Review.  Moderators can migrate anywhere.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Flag for mod attention]

Note: You may need better justification than my example.

Comment: @OmegaMan Haha, no problem =)

Comment: Hand-drawn circle and arrows and unicorns rule, and compel up votes.